# Summation of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $f(a)$ be the sequence defined by 
>   $$f(a)=\left[\frac{a^2+8a+10}{a+9}\right]$$ 
>   where $[x]$ is the largest integer that does not exceed $x$.
>
> Find the value of $$\sum_{x=1}^{30}f(x).$$

Comment: A rather straightforward method would be to compute it with the aid of, say, a computer.

Answer (score 6):

Since

$$\frac{a^2+8a+10}{a+9}=a-1+\frac{11}{a+9}\;,$$

we have

$$\left\lfloor\frac{a^2+8a+10}{a+9}\right\rfloor=a-1+\left\lfloor\frac{11}{a+9}\right\rfloor$$ whenever $a$ is an integer. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{a=1}^{30}\frac{a^2+8a+10}{a+9}&=\sum_{a=1}^{30}\left(a-1+\left\lfloor\frac{11}{a+9}\right\rfloor\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{a=1}^{29}a+\sum_{a=1}^{30}\left\lfloor\frac{11}{a+9}\right\rfloor\\\\
&=\frac12(29)(30)+2\\\\
&=437\;,
\end{align*}$$

since $\dfrac{11}{a+9}<1$ for $a>2$.